# DirectoryServices Search Out of Range Error

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, directoryservices, outofrangeexception, directorysearcher

I am trying to get a full list of users along with their email address. After trying a lot of things the below has finally gave me some form of joy however I get this error this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to prevent this?
The full code is below.

```
Dim entry As DirectoryEntry = Nothing
Dim search As DirectorySearcher = Nothing
entry = New DirectoryEntry()
search = New DirectorySearcher()
search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(mail=*@companyname.com*))"
search.Sort.PropertyName = "cn"
Dim result As SearchResultCollection = search.FindAll()
For Each res As SearchResult In result
    Dim Name = res.Properties("cn")(0).ToString()
    Dim Email = res.Properties("mail")(0).ToString()
WindowsForm1.ListBox1.Items.Add(Name & " <" & Email & ">")
Next
entry.Dispose()
search.Dispose()
result.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is assuming res.Properties has the keys "cn" and "mail" with values that are arrays that have at least one element in them.

**res.Properties("cn")(0).ToString()**

This says 'convert the first element in the array from res.Properties whose key name is **cn** to a string.' That kind of sounds confusing because it is. And it assumes you *know*:

1. res.Properties has an element whose key name is **cn**
2. That element has a value that is a type of an array
3. That array has an element in it at location 0
4. The element at the location can be converted to a string

Try checking these before attempting to access them. I haven't looked into any type-specific functionality but below should work.

```
Dim Name, Email as String
If Not IsNothing(res.Properties("cn")) AndAlso res.Properties("cn").Count > 0 AndAlso Not IsNothing(res.Properties("mail")) AndAlso res.Properties("mail").Count > 0 Then

    Name = res.Properties("cn")(0)
    Email = res.Properties("mail")(0)
End If
```

This should be more cleaned up but the idea and root cause is the same - we're trying to avoid accessing values of an array until we're sure we have an array that has a value to be accessed in the first place. Always validate your data.